# How to handle when the height of the bar is more than y-axis value and then bar is cut off from there using core plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I am displaying the bar chart using core plot. But I am facing one problem that is when height is more than y-axis label then the bar is cut off and it is not ending as other bar ends. How I should handle this when the value is more than Y-axis label value.

Please help me out of this.
Thank you.
Madan Mohan

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Ray Wenderlich tutorial of CorePlot (Bar graph) [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2). Find the method `-(void)configureGraph`. Here you can understand that When you are configuring the graph you should specify the plot range for the y-axis:

```
[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin)
                             length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax)]
```

The `yMax` variable sets the plot range for the y-axis.

Comment: The length should be `yMax - yMin`.